# Javascript closure (using parameter name to define an object in the same function)

Tags: javascript

I have the below code. Need to know how "a" is used as a function parameter, and then inside the same  function it again used as object "a" to call another function.And what is mean by  "a || {}"  at the end of code.

```
E.martin= function (a) {
a = mergein({ api_url: "/somefolder/",
          json_parameter: false,
          channel_id: null,
          after_response_hook: null},
          a || {});
```

Comment: `a || {}` simply means that if `a` is null, undefined or otherwise evaluates to false use the value of `{}` - an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Here 'a' is a function arg
E.martin= function (a) {

//Here 'a' is overwritten by the returned value from mergein
a = mergein({ api_url: "/somefolder/",
      json_parameter: false,
      channel_id: null,
      after_response_hook: null},

      //Here 'a' is send to the function, if it's not null/false.
      //if 'a' is null/false an empty object will be created and sent instead.
      a || {});
```

`mergein` does probably add a function to the arg `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the a || {}; section

This is a way to check if "a" already exists. If it does then use it, if it doesnt the create it as a new object.

Comment: "a || {}" means if a is not null, undefined, or false, create a new object using the shorthand  {}. It's the same as a || new Object();

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

To answer your actual question (I originally thought you were having issues with the code), the `a || {}` part of the code says "either use 'a' or if 'a' is not defined then use a new empty object ({})".

**ADVICE**:

I would advise you return the a in your `E.martin` method as objects in JavaScript are not hard referenced. If you don't return the result, you'll likely lose the original object that you sent to the method.

Let's say `mergein` is a method that concatenates two objects:

```
function mergein(new_obj, old_obj){

    for(var i in new_obj){

        old_obj[i] = new_obj[i];   

    }

    return old_obj;

}
```

If we have your original method, we will lose our original object keys/values when we get our result back:

```
E.martin = function (a) {

    a = mergein({ api_url: "/somefolder/",
          json_parameter: false,
          channel_id: null,
          after_response_hook: null},
          a || {});

}

var b = {foo:'bar'};

var result = martin(b);

console.log(result['foo']); // error
```

If we return our `a` object, we'll get back our original object with the added keys/values:

```
E.martin = function (a) {

    return mergein({ api_url: "/somefolder/",
          json_parameter: false,
          channel_id: null,
          after_response_hook: null},
          a || {});

}

var b = {foo:'bar'};

var result = martin(b);

console.log(result['foo']); // 'bar'
```